# Style of cell not updating on sorting - Flexmonster js

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, flexmonster

I'm validating data on server side. I need to highlight the cell based on invalid data got through API call response. On initial render, I set style for invalid data, but on sort cell label values getting sorted but styles don't update.

[Image - On initial render table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0tAt.png)

[Image - After sort table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv6Vz.png)

I need to sort cell label value with its styles set on initial render. How to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)